# Comparing JavaScript and PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php

I need to compare a javascript variable to a php variable.

```
var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
        if(exam == other){
```

Is this the correct way to compare such variables? It is not working, but perhaps the problem is something else.
The code is used in the function excamTables() below,

```
function examTables(){
    var exam = this.value;
    console.log(exam);
    var resultArray = [];
    <?php foreach($exams as $element): ?>
    var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
        if(exam == other){
            resultArray = <?php echo json_encode($subs[$element], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
        }
    <?php endforeach; ?>


        var strOption = "";
        strOption = "<table>";
        var keys1 = Object.keys(resultArray);
            keys1.forEach(function(item1){
                var keys2 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1]);
                keys2.forEach(function(items2){
                    var keys3 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1][items2]);
                        value = resultArray[item1][items2];/*Need to not repeat subjects. This should be done in php file when selecting from DB*/
                        strOption += "<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
                });
            });
        strOption += "</table>";

    var table = document.getElementById("examTables");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerHTML = strOption;
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row);
}

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('year');
    for(var index in checkboxes){
        //bind event to each checkbox
        checkboxes[index].onchange = examTables;
    }
```

This post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414496/equating-javascript-and-php-variables) discussed this and uses

```
echo json_encode($element);
```

So I tried that but it is not working,

```
function examTables(){
    var exam = this.value;
    console.log(exam);
    var resultArray = [];
    <?php foreach($exams as $element): ?>
    var other = <?php echo json_encode($element); ?>;
        if(exam == other){
            resultArray = <?php echo json_encode($subs[$element], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
        }else{
            resultArray = <?php echo json_encode($subs['AP'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
        }
    <?php endforeach; ?>

        var strOption = "";
        strOption = "<table>";
        var keys1 = Object.keys(resultArray);
            keys1.forEach(function(item1){
                var keys2 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1]);
                keys2.forEach(function(items2){
                    var keys3 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1][items2]);
                        value = resultArray[item1][items2];/*Need to not repeat subjects. This should be done in php file when selecting from DB*/
                        strOption += "<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
                });
            });
        strOption += "</table>";

    var table = document.getElementById("examTables");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    cell.innerHTML = strOption;
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How are you comparing them looks ok. What is returning the $element variable? Use a var_dump.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two JSON objects you should consider evaluating equality by a common property value, otherwise you will have to `JSON.stringify` them both and compare the result.

**Slow**

```
<?php $element = json_encode($anObject); ?>
var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
if(JSON.stringify(exam) == JSON.stringify(other)) {
    // ...
}
```

**Quick**

```
<?php $element = json_encode($anObject); ?>
var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
if(exam.prop == other.prop) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Another thing: you should to be careful about how you are echoing a value in PHP which will then be interpreted by JavaScript. For example:

**This PHP...**

```
$element = "elementValue";
var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
```

**...produces this JavaScript**

```
var other = elementValue;
```

As you can see, PHP has simply inserted the string "elementValue" into the page. But when JavaScript comes to interpret the expression `var other = elementValue;` it will expect `elementValue` to be a pre-defined variable. To avoid this, echo the value of `$element` in PHP by surrounding it in quotes, so we have:

**This PHP...**

```
$element = "elementValue";
var other = "<? echo $element; ?>";
```

**...produces this JavaScript**

```
var other = "elementValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var other = "<?php echo $element; ?>";
```

instead of

```
var other = <?php echo $element; ?>;
```

To check if you are getting the value of $element in other, use alert(other);

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work now. Thanks for all your help,

```
function examTables(){
    var exam = this.value;
    var resultArray = [];
    var i = 0;
    <?php foreach($exams as $element): ?>
    other = <?php echo json_encode($element);?>;
    if(exam == other)
    {
         console.log("exam: " + exam + " is " + "element: " + other);
         resultArray = <?php echo json_encode($subs[$element], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
    }   
    console.log(resultArray);
    i++;
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        var strOption = "";
        strOption = "<table>";
        var keys1 = Object.keys(resultArray);
            keys1.forEach(function(item1){
                var keys2 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1]);
                keys2.forEach(function(items2){
                    var keys3 = Object.keys(resultArray[item1][items2]);
                        value = resultArray[item1][items2];
                        strOption += "<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
                });
            });
        strOption += "</table>";
    console.log(strOption);
    var table = document.getElementById("examTables");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var tableinner = document.createElement("table");
    var rowinner = document.createElement("tr");
    var cellinner = document.createElement("td");
    cellinner.innerHTML = strOption;
    rowinner.appendChild(cellinner);
    tableinner.appendChild(rowinner);
    cell.appendChild(tableinner);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row);
}
```

Thanks